# How to set page number at the right side of the page

Tags: page-numbering

I want the page number to be centered on the right side of the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not forget to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to clarify your problem. Besides, isn´t "...page number to be centered on the right side of the page" a little contradictory?

Comment: @Roland I think OP means vertically centered - but I agree we need an MWE in order to advise the OP how this can be done.